# Problema background image em div

Tags: html5, css3, div, background

Estou com um problema em uma div. O nome dela é

```
<div id="content-homepage">
```

Acontece que essa div tem alguns conteúdos dentro (textos, títulos e um botão), e quando insiro a imagem através do

```
#content-homepage {
    background-image: url(../img/back.jpg);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

A imagem não aparece. Eu queria que ela aparecesse e ficasse em toda a tela. Independente do dispositivo, que ela se ajustasse e ficasse em toda a tela.

Comment: Gabriel coloque um valor de antura para essa div `#content-homepage` tipo `height: 50px;` e veja se a imagem aparece. Ou coloque um texto dentro da div para ele ter ago dentro. Outra coisa, verifique se a extensão da sua imagem é mesmo JPG ou se é PNG ou GIF por exemplo

Comment: A imagem realmente é JPG. Coloquei o height e um width, e ela agora aparece, mas não em toda a tela.

Comment: Cara acho que entendi seu problema então. Da uma olhada na resposta lá e testa ai pra ver se é o seu problema. Qq coisa é só deixar um comentário lá que te dou uma força

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara seu problema é que vc colocou 100% de altura na `div`, mas 100% de que? Para o código renderizar com uma altura em % é preciso que o pai tenha uma altura. Então caso sua `div` seja filha direta do `body` coloque 100% de antura no `body`, assim a `div` vai ter 100% da altura do pai entender.

Se seu CSS ficar assim provavelmente vai funciona. E repare que eu coloquei `background-size: cover;` isso vai fazer com que a imagem cubra o conteúdo inteiro da `div` 100% x 100%

```css
html, body {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
#content-homepage {
    background-image: url(https://placecage.com/300/180);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-homepage"></div>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado, Hugo.

Comment: @GabrielMarinho dmr o principal é a explicação, vai te ajudar em outras situações. principalmente quando se usa altura em %

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, tente isso.

```
#content-homepage {
margin-top: 0%;
background-image: url(../img/back.jpg);
background-size: contain;
background-position: center;
height: fit-content;
width: 100%;
width: auto;
```

}

Comment: Não aparece. Só os itens dentro da div, mais nada.

Comment: Poderia fornecer uma imagem ?

Answer (score -1):

Tente usar

```
height: 100vh;
```

Ao invés de

```
height: 100%;
```

Poderia mandar o seu css?

Comment: Funcionou! Mas fica aparecendo a barra de rolagem na página. Será que a margem/borda de outros itens?

Comment: Isso quer dizer que a sua div está puxando o tamanho da div paterna dela, que deve ser 0, quando você usa o view port height você seta o tamanho da div como se fosse os pixels da tela pela sua altura, tente colocar a propriedade height:100%, na div pai da que você está utilizando como fundo. se não tiver nenhuma div paterna utilize a propriedade height: 100% no body e html

Comment: cole esse codigo no topo do seu css.         
 
 body,html{height:100%;}

e use novamente height:100%, na div que você que o fundo.

Comment: https://codepen.io/AntonioBan/pen/aQeWVz